# Private CocoaPods repo with specific constraints

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

I've searched around and looked at guides for establish a private CocoaPods repository for my team, and I can't seem to nail down what I'm shooting for.

First, my constraints/requirements, in decreasing order of priority:

1. Pods should be usable through several different projects. (obviously)
2. Special configuration required for an individual developer's machine should be minimal.
3. We have limited number of private repositories available on GitHub; ideally, all Pods should be nested within a single private GitHub repo, rather than a separate repo per pod.

What I'd really like is to have a single repo with the following structure:

```
├─┬ Specs
  └─-MHView
     └-0.0.1 ... etc
  └─-MHWidget
├─┬ Pods
  └─-MHView         
  └─-MHWidget...
```

I guess I'm not really sure if this is a) possible, and b) the correct usage of a private pods repo

Answer (score 1):

1. Isn't that solved by CocoaPods itself? In my team we reuse private pods on several projects in same fashion as open source one
2. Each team member should have access to private spec repo. Running 2 command line commands can be wrapped in shell script, but that is one time action on single machine.
3. You can store all pods in one repo and grab source files from different subfolders. [Podspec source_files](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source_files)

I would suggest to separate specs repo from pods one. More radical will be to setup self hosted Gitlab instance. But that's matter of taste :)